# Print ..count.. value in geom_label()

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have been trying to access the value of ..count.. in ggplot2 is there anyway to access this value? At the moment I'm getting the following error:

> Error: Aesthetics must be valid computed stats. Problematic
>   aesthetic(s): label = ..count...  Did you map your stat in the wrong
>   layer?

How can I access that value that has been computed before? Here's the code:

```
transfusion %>%
  mutate(Group = ifelse(whether.he.she.donated.blood.in.March.2007 == 0, "Didn't donate", "Donated")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Group, fill = Group)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 500, by = 100)) +
  ylab("Count of people") +
  ggtitle("People who donated blood in march 2007") +
  geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..))) +
  geom_label(aes(label = ..count..))
```

Comment: I'd just calculate the counts beforehand and use that as the data rather than relying on ggplot to do the aggregation for you

Comment: Francisco, since you are using `dplyr`, it's "best practice" to use `dplyr::if_else` in place of `ifelse`, for several reasons. In this example it behaves exactly the same, but there are many cases where `ifelse` has problems that `if_else` does not.

Comment: Thanks  a lot for the recommendation, I'll be refactoring those ifelse!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution using `..count..`. All you have to do is to ask `geom_label` to compute it.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

transfusion %>%
  mutate(Group = ifelse(whether.he.she.donated.blood.in.March.2007 == 0, "Didn't donate", "Donated")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Group, fill = Group)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "dodge") +
  geom_label(stat = 'count', aes(label = ..count..), 
             vjust = -0.1,
             show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 500, by = 100)) +
  ylab("Count of people") +
  ggtitle("People who donated blood in march 2007") +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(2, 0.8, 2, 0.8))
```

[image]

## Data

```
set.seed(1234)
transfusion <- data.frame(
  whether.he.she.donated.blood.in.March.2007 = rbinom(800, 1, prob = c(0.3, 0.7))
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, seems so easy now but I couldn't figure it out!

Answer (score 1):

Using `mtcars` as example data this can be achieved by using `stat = "count"` inside `geom_label` and using `after_stat` (new in `ggplot2 3.3.0`) to map `count` on `label`

```r
library(ggplot2)

#mutate(Group = ifelse(whether.he.she.donated.blood.in.March.2007 == 0, "Didn't donate", "Donated")) %>%
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(cyl), fill = factor(cyl))) + 
  #scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 500, by = 100)) +
  #ylab("Count of people") +
  #ggtitle("People who donated blood in march 2007") +
  geom_bar() +
  geom_label(aes(label = after_stat(count)), stat = "count")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>